# What are the shortcuts in Xcode to show/hide Navigator, Debug, and Utilities?

Tags: xcode, keyboard-shortcuts

Xcode has these buttons to show or hide the Navigator, Debug area, and Utilities:

[image]

What are the keyboard shortcuts to do the same?

Answer (score 103, accepted):

In order to show or hide the Navigator, Debug area, and Utilities, use the following shortcuts.

- Navigator: <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>
- Debug area: <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd>
- Utilities: <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>

*(Those are zeros, not the letter O.)*

Here is an image from [this article](http://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/03/23/xcode-keyboard-shortcuts/) (which itself was adapted from [this blog post](http://www.rsaunders.co.uk/2011/11/xcode-shortcuts.html)):

[image]

## Useful links about Xcode shortcuts:

- [Xcode Efficiency Tips: Keyboard Shortcuts](http://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/03/23/xcode-keyboard-shortcuts/)
- [14 Xcode Time Saving Keyboard Shortcuts - Memorize and Improve Your Productivity](http://iphonedev.tv/blog/2014/9/15/14-xcode-time-saving-shortcuts-memorize-and-improve-your-productivity)
- [11 Xcode Keyboard Shortcuts to Make You More Productive](http://roadfiresoftware.com/2015/05/useful-xcode-keyboard-shortcuts-for-developers/)
- [Menu Command Shortcuts](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/xcode_help-command_shortcuts/MenuCommands/MenuCommands014.html)

Comment: I was about to complain about those not working but then I realized that I misread them and that those are 0s (the number), not Os (the letter).